# 4 TABLES INNER JOIN SQL STATEMENT

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have this database structure...

[image: database]

(It´s on spanish, hope doesn´t matter) and I made this query using inner join but I don´t get any result so I guess I did something wrong... This is my query...

```
SELECT TBoleta.NroSerie+'-'+TBoleta.NroBoleta Boleta, TBoleta.Fecha, 
TAlumno.APaterno+' '+TAlumno.AMaterno+' '+TAlumno.Nombres as Apellidos_y_Nombres, 
TGrupoModulo.Modulo + ' ' + TGrupoModulo.Seccion + ' ' + TGrupoModulo.Turno,
 TBoleta.Monto  

FROM        TMatricula 
        inner join TAlumno on TMatricula.CodAlumno = TAlumno.CodAlumno
        inner join TBoleta on TBoleta.NroMatricula = TMatricula.NroMatricula
        inner join TGrupoModulo on TGrupoModulo.CodGrupoModulo =    TMatricula.CodGrupoModulo
```

Please... I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: How are you doing `inner join TAlumno on TBoleta.CodAlumno = TAlumno.CodAlumno` when `TBoleta` doesn't have a column `CodAlumno`?

Comment: I messed up somewhere... the correct query is this one...

Comment: Anyway... I don´t get any results ¿is everything ok?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your updated query looks correct now. I made an equivalent query and was successfully able to get results. Could be some typographical error. Look in your SQL log after you run the query. Also, could truly be no results. You are joining a lot of tables together, and inner join will throw out null values on either side of the join. Try LEFT JOINS instead. Can't read Spanish, so can't get anything from context to help you that way = )

Answer (score 3):

For starters, this attribute doesn't exist; TBoleta.CodAlumno

Edit: Now that your query appears to be compiling fine, remember that inner joins necessitate data from each join to have matching values. If one of the joins don't, you get no data back. Analyze your data to figure this out. You could also do left outer joins at first, then move to inner joins step by step.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a cursory guess, but this line:

```
inner join TAlumno on TBoleta.CodAlumno = TAlumno.CodAlumno
```

appears to be incorrect, because TBoleta doesn't have a column named CodAlumno. You should check to see if you're getting any errors whilst running this query.

Answer (score 0):

If any field column is empty, then result is not displayed.
further if you want to display with `empty` or `null` values you can use `LEFT JOIN` in your query